# Ignoring scroll event when browser back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, browser, vuejs2

In my site, *list page* loads all data in table rows. It keeps loading when user scrolls to the bottom of page(infinite scroll). This works fine. User can click a link from row and lands on another page on subdomain. When user clicks back button to *list page*, it fires scroll event and loads data. Sometime scroll event fired few time(say 3 to 5 api calls happens)

Site is built with Vuejs. I have tried few suggestion like `window.onpopstate`, vuejs' navigation guards. `window.onpopstate` doesn't work. Vuejs' `beforeRouteEnter` not helping. Because even before a flag is captured in `beforeRouteEnter`, scroll event fires.

Is there any way to stop scroll event being fired by back button click?

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly what you are looking for:

```
if ( 'scrollRestoration' in history ) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```